# Hiding Ip in JavaScript WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, ip

i'm having those JavaScript WebSocket variables -
`var Server = new WebSocket('ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9300');
 var Server2 = new WebSocket('ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9301');`
("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" are Ips. )
The problem is that, the ips are viewable in the "View Source" browser option. I don't want them to be vissible for security reasons(DDoS attacks and so on...). Is there any possible way i can hide or crypt just the Ips so that they aren't usable or vissible at all from the client side(not only in the "View Source" option)?

Comment: answer is - no, you cannot hide this ip, even if you encrypt it - you still will see ip in network log

Comment: You can't hide the IP, that is, you could use an URL instead, but doing a whois lookup would be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was tempted to downvote and joke, because your question is quite silly the way you put it. You can't hide the identity of the server you're connecting to. Even if you encrypt it in the source, it would be trivial to just log the connection to the (necessarily decrypted) IP.

Except if you're connecting through some proxy. Though that doesn't really solve your problem. The proxy itself could be attacked, or your servers through it.

There are ways to mitigate attacks such as DDoS but nothing foolproof. I'm sure you can find more at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) by asking the right questions.

Comment: Irony detected. Hiding the identity or even the existence of a remote server connection from the client/user would be mighty handy when writing a DDoS anyhow. Up voted for asking ServerFault as the way to address this.